# How do I stream Rhapsody RAD/EA music files?

Tags: mp3, audio-streaming, aac, rhapsody

I'm writing an iOS app that interacts with the [Rhapsody music service](http://www.rhapsody.com/) [SDK](http://webservices.rhapsody.com/). I'm stuck at the point where I need to combine the RAD and EA portions of the music file. According to their docs:

> After the track playback information has been returned, you can now
>   begin retrieving the Rhapsody audio data. First, load the media URL
>   property returned from the getTrackPlaybackInfos method into your
>   client. Most of the Rhapsody formats allowed for streaming require a
>   security method used by Rhapsody called RAD/EA. The RAD/EA security
>   model allows for immediate download via HTTP of the majority of the
>   track (known as the RAD portion of the audio). The client then
>   downloads a small encrypted portion of the file (known as the EA
>   portion of the file) every 30 seconds to constitute the entire music
>   file.
>
> If the media URL contains a RAD, call the getEA method to get the
>   essential audio (EA). Use the session identifier, RAD version (3,
>   unless otherwise told by your Rhapsody Direct representative), format,
>   and bit rate returned from the cal to getTrackPlaybackInfos. You must
>   call the getEA method multiple times to play back the entire audio
>   track. The position parameter contains the offset in the EA block at
>   which to start retrieving the audio data, and the count parameter
>   contains the actual number of bytes to be returned. For example, on
>   the first call to getEA, you would set the position parameter to 0 and
>   could set the count parameter to 4096. This would return 4096 bytes of
>   audio data starting at the beginning of the track. On the second cal
>   to get EA, you would then set the position parameter to 4096 and the
>   count parameter to 4096. On the third call, the position parameter
>   would be 8192 and the count parameter 4096. Continue calling the getEA
>   method until the entire track has played.

I can find the RAD file easy enough. But what I'm not clear on is how I re-combine the RAD and EA files into a streamable/playable media file? I think this is the 1st time Google has failed me. I cannot even find a hint about how to proceed.

Comment: Did you manage to stream it?

Comment: No. We could not get much help from Rhapsody either. After talking to them it sounds like they're redesigning/upgrading their system & api, not devoting many resources to this old one. So we're waiting/hoping they do, and that it's up-to-par with the api's of rdio and spotify.

Answer (score 0):

1. About RAD/EA: on the Rhapsody site there are some samples how to get a playable music file from the input RAD and EA files (samples in Java and C++)
2. RAD file we can download directly
3. Problem with EA file - how to create it? In the documentation it's written that we need to call getEA method every 30 seconds, but the next questions arise here:

   - How to create an EA file (that as I understand should have a special structure with the special file headers) from the received from the WS getEA method bytes?
   - How to handle the OFFLINE mode if we need to call getEA method every 30 seconds to decode the RAD file?

If you have something to add - please feel free...
I will be glad for any new info.

**Solution:**

1. Download RAD file.
2. Call getEA - we get here an array of some kind of the ASCII codes. Please see here how to convert it in the bytes array in Java: [ASCII codes => string of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438003/ascii-codes-string-of-characters/14438072#14438072)
3. ```
           RadStream rs = new RadStream(getRadSource());
           Log.e(TAG, "" + rs.getHeader());

           EaStream es = new EaStream(getEaSource());
           Log.e(TAG, "" + es.getHeader());

           RadEaStream radea = new RadEaStream(rs, es);

           int counter = 0;
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWMA);
           for (int c = radea.read(); c >= 0; c = radea.read()) {
               out.write(c);
               counter += 1;
           }
           out.close();
   ```

For me it works.

Comment: I've been able to get their sample code to work fine. I'm also able to download both the RAD and the EA portions via the api. My problem is when I apply their sample code to the files I get from the api it fails to decode. I've not been able to get past that, and have not been able to get any help from Rhapsody thus far.