# ASCII codes => string of characters

Tags: java, ascii

I have the next string of the ASCII codes:

```
[-76,-96,-80,106,-58,106,-1,34,7,123,-84,101,51]
```

What is the best way to convert it in the string of the characters of these codes values?
Are there any pitfalls here?

Comment: Those aren't all ASCII - you've got values which are negative Java byte values, so logically unsigned values over 127. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding.

Comment: These values are not part of the standard ascii table, so depending on the version of the table you are using they will be different symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn it into a corresponding byte array and then instantiate `new String(byteArray)`.

```
String [] strings = input.substring(1, input.length()-1).split(",");
byte[] bytes = new byte[strings.length];
int i = 0;
for (String s : strings) bytes[i++] = Byte.parseByte(s);
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

In place of "UTF-8" use your proper character encoding. It could be CP-1250, ISO-8859-1, or similar.

Comment: only:
String [] strings = input.substring(1, input.length()-2).split(",");

Comment: You may have some extra whitespace at the end, `length()-1` is appropriate for the string you have posted. Use `input.trim().substring(...` to make sure you eliminate whitespace.